# Access Select tag elements values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

I have created an Enum with three values.
In create view file, the Enum presented as Select tag.

I want to hide and show (Toggle) a specific field according to the value of the chosen element in Select tag.

When I run the code and change the selected item, The (SlideDown) function execute automatically. But I want that function to execute only when the value of the chosen item Equals to 2. (Not when I change)

Here is Select tag part in the create view file:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Certificate" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="crfct" asp-for="Certificate" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Certificate>()" class="form-control"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Certificate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="crfctcost">
        <label asp-for="CertificateCost" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CertificateCost" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CertificateCost" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

And jQuery code:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#crfctcost").hide();
            $("#crfct").change(function () {
                var selectedCertificate = $('#crfct').find(":selected").val();
                if (selectedCertificate == "2"); {
                    $("#crfctcost").slideDown();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.  you have added a ';' in if

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#crfctcost").hide();
                $(document).on('change','#crfct',function (e) {
                    var selectedCertificate = $(this).val();
                    if (selectedCertificate == 2){
                        $("#crfctcost").slideDown();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much It Works Successfully